Play Store in-app subscription is displaying the subscription type as "1.99/min" instead of "/week."
I have added subscription in my flutter app. The issue is on the UI its showing "1.99/min" whereas i set "1.99/week".
When i debugged, its showing billing period as P1W. 
I also checked playstore console, and it looks like everything is fine there as well.



This is what its showing on the UI.

This is my flutter code.
  Future<void> buyNonConsumable(String productTitle) async {
    // Check if a purchase is already in progress

    late PurchaseParam purchaseParam;
    productId = productTitle.toLowerCase();

    if (isPurchaseInProgress.value == true) {
      print("Purchase already in progress");
      return;
    }


    if(Platform.isAndroid){
      purchaseParam = GooglePlayPurchaseParam(productDetails: await _getProductDetails(productTitle.toLowerCase()));
    }else{
      purchaseParam =
          PurchaseParam(productDetails: await _getProductDetails(productTitle.toLowerCase()));
    }

    // Perform the purchase
    //final PurchaseParam purchaseParam = PurchaseParam(productDetails: await _getProductDetails(productTitle.toLowerCase()));
    await InAppPurchase.instance.buyNonConsumable(purchaseParam: purchaseParam);
    await Future.delayed(3000.milliseconds);
  }


This is because you are testing, for real purchases it will show one week.
Here is the link to the relevant documentation https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/test#renewals

